# SqlServer Update Case statement

Tags: sql-server

I have a Staging and Master table with columns like this
Step 1:

```
Create table Staging(
    ID varchar(10) not null, 
    name varchar(100) not null, 
    createddate datetime not null
)
```

Step 2:

```
insert into Staging('1','Amy','2014-01-01');
```

Step 3:

```
Create table Master(
    ID varchar(10) not null, 
    name varchar(100) not null, 
    createddate datetime not null,
    verifieddate datetime not null
)
```

Step 4:

```
insert into master(
    select id,
            name,
            createddate,
            createddate 
    from    staging s 
    left outer join master on m on m.id=s.id where m.id is null);
```

Day 2:

```
delete from Staging;
insert into Staging('1','Amy','2014-02-01');
insert into Staging('2','Binny','2014-01-01');
```

I run Step 4 that inserts ID=2 to Master. I want to update ID=1 by keeping the createddate same but verifieddate should be changed to 2014-02-01.
So, I wrote update statement like this

```
update Master set VerifiedDate = 
(case when i.verifieddate < a.createddate then a.createddate end) 
      FROM Staging a inner join 
      Master i 
     on i.id=a.[ID] where i.verifieddate < a.createddate
```

It is not working. Any suggestions.

Comment: What is not working. An exception? Wrong updated rows? The output is not like expected?

Comment: How would step 4 insert ID = 2?  It looks like there is only 1 record in staging.  Any reason your IDs are varchar instead of int identity(1,1)?

Comment: @Dave.Gugg, ID's are alphanumeric in this table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In theory, you should be able to do it with an `UPDATE` statement like:

```
UPDATE m

SET         VerifiedDate = s.CreatedDate

FROM        Master AS m

INNER JOIN  Staging AS s
    ON      m.Id = s.Id
    AND     s.CreatedDate > m.VerifiedDate
```